# raising custom events to allow web user controls to intercommunicate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 web user controls, both inherit the same base class which extends UserControl. I want to raise an event on one and the other should be aware of it. both are on the same page however the 2nd control never handles the custom event i raised on the 1st one ! any ideas ? please just point to an implementation of possible (BTW, i'm googling it since morning but no luck !)

Comment: Can you show us the source code of what you have so far?

Comment: Here's a similar question (though it talks about different nested controls on the same page) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550283/asp-net-event-delegation-between-user-controls/2550325 You'll have to do something similar to the answer suggested to that question to attach control events together.

Comment: I have tried a lot of approaches, I will test this one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do the following:

1) create an event in control 1.
2) create a public method in control 2, that gets called if the event in control 1 is raised
3) subscribe to the event of control 1 (where you instanciate them, e.g. another control, a content page or a master page)
4) inside the event handler from 3), call the method created in 2)

5) do the other thing around, if control 2 should communicate with control 1

This all require server-side execution. I'm sure there might be also client-side solutions.

**Edit after comment**:
There are only two possible communication ways I can think of:
1) the controls don't know each other and therefore can't communicate directly. => you need a third control/page/masterpage/whatever (database, service etc) to enable the communication
2) the controls reference each other and therfore can communicate directly => very bad OOP. If you use this, you do not understand OOP at all and should consider your job

Feel free to chose one of the options.

Comment: it seams that the parent page should be involved. can you recommend a solution is completely decoupled without having the parent page/control being involved in registering the custom event ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Raise Events from User Controls using Delegates

Look [Here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2004/10/06/Easily-Raise-Events-From-ASP.NET-ASCX-User-Controls.aspx) for an example

Comment: it seams that the parent page should be involved. can you recommend a solution which is completely decoupled without having the parent page/control being involved in registering the custom event ?